# Spectrogram Matlab

Tags: matlab, spectrogram

I have the following code in matlab:

```
[Sound Fs bits] = wavread('a.wav');
```

Now i have to use the function spectrogram and plot it (i have to give the function spectrogram the following arguments: Sound and Fs and the function is suposed to return a vector with the frequence composition of the signal and a vector with the frequences in wich the composition was calculated).

My doubt is: how do i use the function with these specifications? Can someone help me?

Comment: What have you tried, and what problems did you encounter? If you don't know how to start, then you need to be a bit more specific about exactly what your difficulties are.

Comment: So i did: [Sound Fs bits] = wavread('a.wav');
Now i have to do a plot with the amplitudes and the frequences, and i have to get the frequences from spectrogram, i am trying something like:

[S,F,T] = spectrogram(Sound, Fs), it keeps saying:
The length of the segments cannot be greater than the length of the input signal.

And i dont know other way to do it. What i would want to do, would be:
plot(frequences_of_the_signal,amplitude_of_the_signal)

Did that explanation make it clear? Sorry for bad english, not my native language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`spectrogram`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/signal/ref/spectrogram.html) function is expecting a vector windowing argument in its second argument, if supplied. You need to supply values for all the arguments **up to and including** `Fs`. But these arguments can optionally be empty, so you can do:

```
[S, F, T] = spectrogram(Sound, [], [], [], Fs);
% Sample rate is the fifth argument        ^^
```

Although note that, to use this function properly, you really should understand what the rest of the parameters do/mean... (I'm not going to explain them here; you could write entire books on the topic, and indeed many have been)

Comment: Hum i see, now if i would use the plot function, would it be:
plot(F, S) or plot(F, Sound) ?

Comment: `plot(F, S)` will plot your spectrogram, `plot(F, Sound)` is meaningless because `F` is a vector of frequencies and `Sound` is in the time domain...

Comment: Yeah i figured it out. I think thats it. Just one more thing:
If i write: spectrogram(Sound, [], [], [], Fs) on matlab it will show me one figure but if i do:
plot(F, S) it will show me something different, it is normal? If it is, what's the difference?

Comment: Pay attention to the axes labels: `spectrogram` with no output arguments will plot it in dB / Hz (to convert, you can do `10 * log10(S)`).